# Como dar a opção para o utilizador escolher a pasta de destino em BATCH?

Tags: batch, vbs

Não pretendo dar entrada do destino manualmente, como por exemplo:

```
set /p destino=Escolha o local de destino:
robocopy /s /e pasta %destino%
```

**RESOLVIDO:**  Usando cmd (set & for) + PowerShell (new-object & .BrowseForFolder)

```
    set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^.BrowseForFolder(0,'Por favor, escolha um destino para guardar os seus dados.',0,0).self.path""
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "folder=%%I"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>**`• Testado nas seguintes versões do Windows®:`**</kbd>

<kbd>**`XP Pro 32 bits, 7 Pro 64 bits, 8.0 Pro 64 bits & 10 Pro 64 bits`**</kbd>

---

• Existe a opção de utilizar recursos do **VBS** para a **escolha de pasta** via **janela** / **GUI**,  usando um **bat** que cria em tempo de execução, um **arquivo.VBS** e executando de forma que salve a **pasta** escolhida.

**<kbd>`• Navegando até a pasta alvo usando a interface gráfica e mouse/rato:`</kbd>**

• Para uso num **bat** capturando na **variável** a pasta **selecionada/escolhida**, use:

**<kbd>`@for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%i in ('cscript //nologo escolhe_pasta.vbs')do @echo/%%i`</kbd>**

• Para uso na **linha de command** capturando na **variável** a pasta **selecionada/escolhida**, use:

**<kbd>`@for /f "tokens=*delims= " %i in ('cscript //nologo escolhe_pasta.vbs')do @echo/%i`</kbd>**

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**<kbd>`Escolher_Pasta.vbs`</kbd>** ::<kbd>**[`• Adaptação de Scripts VBS de autoria de Rob van der Woude's`](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_browsefolder.php)**</kbd>

```vbs
Option Explicit
Dim strPath
strPath = SelectFolder( "" )
If strPath = vbNull Then
    WScript.Echo "Cancelled"
Else
    WScript.Echo strPath
End If
Function SelectFolder( myStartFolder )
    Dim objFolder, objItem, objShell
    On Error Resume Next
    SelectFolder = vbNull
    Set objShell  = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( 0, "Select Folder", 0, myStartFolder )
    If IsObject( objfolder ) Then SelectFolder = objFolder.Self.Path
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objshell  = Nothing
    On Error Goto 0
End Function
```

---

• Respondendo **linha de comando/no_arquivo_bat**

```vbs
rem :: na linha de comando ::
@for /f "tokens=*delims= " %i in ('cscript //nologo escolhe_pasta.vbs')do robocopy /s /e pasta "%~i"

rem :: no arquivo bat ::
@echo off & for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%i in ('cscript //nologo escolhe_pasta.vbs')do robocopy /s /e pasta "%%~i"
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o ***dir*** em um laço ***for*** para percorrer os diretórios retornados:

```
@echo off
rem Habilita a expansão de variáveis de ambiente atrasada
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo.
    echo ** Pastas disponíveis:
    echo.
rem Monta a lista de bases disponíveis
    set CONTADOR=0
    for /f %%i in ('dir /AD /B') do (
       set /a CONTADOR=!CONTADOR! + 1
       echo [!CONTADOR!] - %%i
    )
    echo.
    set /p PASTA=Qual pasta deseja selecionar?
    echo.
rem
rem ....
rem
rem Finalização
     endlocal
```

Comment: Obrigado pela breve resposta Murillo!

Comment: Murillo, existe a possibilidade em apresentação da janela do Windows? Ou seja, que o utilizador procure com o rato a pasta de destino.

Comment: Neste caso você precisaria utilizar um framework visual, como Java Swing, ou JavaFX, ou Delphi, etc.

Comment: Obrigado Murillo!